# Accessing Variables in typescript

Tags: typescript, variables, canvas, html5-canvas

I am using typescript to draw canvas. The problem is I have two methods in a class which need to access the same variables. I tried declaring them like

```js
declare var x;
declare var y

export class Foo {
  constructor() {}
  method1() {
    this.x;
  }

  method2() {
    this.x;
  }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work properly. What am I missing here ?

The answer down seems to work just fine for normal variables. Since I am using canvas. I have something similar like this

```js
export class Foo {
  private x: number = 10;
  private y: number = 20;

  constructor(canvas: HTMLCanvasElement) {
    this.canvas = < HTMLCanvasElement > canvas;
    this.ctx = < CanvasRenderingContext2D > canvas.getContext('2d');
  }
  method1() {
    let width = this.canvas.width;
  }
  method2() {
    let width = this.canvas.width;
  }
}
```

How can I declare them once and use it in two of the methods. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring the variables outside of the class instead of defining them as class properties

```
export class Foo {
  private x;
  private y;
  constructor() {}
  method1() {
    this.x;
  }

  method2() {
    this.x;
  }
}
```

Comment: aah okie thank you. I will change that. I have a variable for canvas width. Since canvas is declared inside the constructor, can I access the variables similarly

Answer (score 1):

The declared variables can be accessed by `x` and `y`, without `this.`

However, if you want your variables to be class-scoped, and defined within the class, you should create your variables as class fields:

```js
export class Foo {
  private x: number;
  private y: number;

  constructor() {}

  public method1() {
    this.x;
  }

  public method2() {
    this.x;
  }
}
```